# Table View Error using Parse - Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am getting a very odd error:
[image]

I have the

```
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
```

bit of code in another table view too, however when I select the cell, I do not get the error. Please can you help me to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated - Thank you.

Comment: have you correctly setup self.tableView as an outlet for the tableview?

Comment: No I don't think so, can you tell me what that looks like please? Sorry, I'm relatively new to programming. @luk2302

Comment: Did you connect the UITableView from the storyboard to your code / variable?

Comment: Oops, no I forgot, but what do I call it when I connect it - or does it not matter? @luk2302

Comment: I didn't have to do it last time and that works so why do I have to do it this time? @luk2302

Comment: Do you invoke that segue from anywhere els such as directly from the cell?  That line will crash if there is no currently selected row because you have force unwrapped the value with !